# When is cash available to be withdrawn from Fidelity after selling stocks?

Tags: stocks, investing, shorting-securities, selling, fidelity

When is cash available to be withdrawn from Fidelity after selling ETFs and stocks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Settlement for equities is T+2 or two days (options are T+1).

Fidelity may have in house restrictions that take longer.  That, you should take up with them.